# Get every frist + second child pass third and four and so on css

Tags: css

I have html like this

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
```

I need to add background color to **1 and 2** and then on **5 and 6** , **9 and 10**

```
&:nth-child(1n+2) {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

But I didnt have luck?

Comment: Yes,, that is correct

Comment: p:nth-child(4n+1), p:nth-child(4n+2)

Comment: p:nth-child(1),p:nth-child(2),p:nth-child(5),p:nth-child(6),p:nth-child(9),p:nth-child(10) {
 background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: 1n+2 is the same as n+2 so it selects everything starting from 2on

Answer (score 3):

I *think* what you're after is:

```
p:nth-child(4n-2),p:nth-child(4n-3) {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Example

```css
p:nth-child(4n-2),p:nth-child(4n-3) {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with a single `:nth-child()`, but you can combine two, like this:

```css
p:nth-child(4n-3),
p:nth-child(4n-2) {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
```